# Drag pin from given location

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, apple-maps

I am using MKMapView fro map. In one view controller I am getting lat long to drop pin in map. Now from preview button user can see that location with pin. Now I have one button by clicking on that button user can drag pin at their desire location. And app can get that lat long. How to implement this

Answer (score 2):

Use this code and also adopt `MKMapViewDelegate`

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView 
didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState 
   fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState 
{
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedAt = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"Pin dropped at %f,%f", droppedAt.latitude, droppedAt.longitude);
    }
}
```

Comment: but only when user press change button it should allow to drag pin to user...how to do that

Comment: you can achieve that by using flag